# Use multiple filters Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, filtering

I have an Angular Material table. I created a search bar which works with the "filter" function of datasource. I created a mat select which works with the "filterpredicate" function of datasource. They both work when I use just one of them. But when I use one, the second will not work fine. I don't know how to use two filters as the same time.

```
search(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.filteredData;
}
```

```
setTypeOfError(error): void {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (myObject: MyObject, filter: string) => {
      // return true if the myObject should be displayed
      return this.selection.length > 0
        ? this.selection.some(error => error === myObject.error)
        : true;
    };

    this.dataSource.filter = 'only used to trigger filter';
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need a `filterPredicate` that handles both fields at the same time. Note that the `filterPredicate` only accepts strings as a filter value - so most probably you will need to serialize your filtering values before passing it to your datasource, and then deserialize it within the `filterPredicate`.

So, you'll want change in either field update your "filter object", serialize it and update the `dataSource.filter` with the new value. This will cause the dataSource to update the value of it's `filteredData`.

Written from top of my head, so fix accordingly if needed be:

```
// It would be better to have this strongly typed to match all the possible filtering criteria.
filterObject = {
    search: "";
    errorTypes: [];
};

// Set this once after your datasource have been initialized, and don't change it afterwards. It needs to handle all combinantions of different filters that you apply.
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (row: MyObject, filter: string) => {
      const filterObj = JSON.parse(filter);
      // A sample filter logic - joining both filters with AND.
      return (!filterObj.search || row.name.includes(filterObj.search)) &&
        (filterObject.errorTypes.length === 0 || filterObject.errorTypes.some(e => e === row.error);
};

// This handles the change of your search. Personally I would bind it to FormControl using reactive forms, but I guess that's a matter of preference
search(e: Event): void {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.filterObject.search = filterValue;
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterObject);
}

// Handle changes of your select. Not sure about the typing here either since you didn't provide stackblitz.
matSelectChanged(selectedItems: string[]): void {
    this.filterObject.errorTypes = selectedItems;
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTypeOfError(error): void {
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (myObject: MyObject, filter: string) => {
  const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  // return true if the myObject should be displayed
  // Write logic to find with selection
  let foundInSelection =  this.selection.length > 0
    ? this.selection.some(error => error === myObject.error)
    : true;

  // Write logic to find with search text
  let foundWithSearchKey = filterValue ? false : true;
  for (const key in myObject) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
      const element: string = object[key];
      if(element) {
        if(element.includes(filterValue)) {
          foundWithSearchKey = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      
    }
  }

  return foundInSelection && foundWithSearchKey;
};

this.dataSource.filter = 'only used to trigger filter';
```

}